# Set menu item text

Tags: java, android, menuitem

I am having trouble setting the menu item text. I want when I start the activity to see the price of all my items in the basket. But whenever I start the shopping list activity I get below error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.MenuItem android.view.Menu.findItem(int)' on a null object reference

This is the code:

```
    public class Shopping_list_activity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private Menu menu;

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.shopping_list_activity); 

            updateMenuTitles();
    }

     @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_shopping_list, menu);
        this.menu = menu;
        return true;
    }

 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.menu_shopping_list_saveList) {
            Toast.makeText(Shopping_list_activity.this, " Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
//        else if (id == R.id.menu_shopping_list_total){
//          Toast.makeText(Shopping_list_activity.this, getPriceOfDisplayedItems() + " total", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

private void updateMenuTitles() {
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_shopping_list_total);
    if (getPriceOfDisplayedItems() > 0) {
        menuItem.setTitle(String.valueOf(getPriceOfDisplayedItems()));
    } else {
        menuItem.setTitle("Total: 0.00");
    }
}
```

The `getPriceOfDisplayedItems()` displays the correct price.

And the XML file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_shopping_list_total"
        android:title="@string/total"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `onCreate` method is called before `onCreateOptions` menu. That's why `this.menu` is `null`. Try moving invocation of `updateMenuTitles` to `onCreateOptionsMenu`.

Comment: Tanks a lot it works ok updating the total in the onCreateOptionsMenu.

Answer (score 0):

You should add menu_shopping_list_saveList item in your xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_shopping_list_total"
        android:title="@string/total"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_shopping_list_saveList"
        android:title="@string/total"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

Comment: This is the item that i am refering, this one i want to change <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_shopping_list_total"
        android:title="@string/total"
        app:showAsAction="always" />